# React two click handling

Tags: reactjs

I have a coverflow in my program that select an image on click, but I need to have functionality that when you click on the chosen image a second time, it links you to a route.

Like with itunes, you can scrowl side by side the coverflow to chose the correct album and click again to access it's page.

The coverflow has the attribute handleSelect. I want the first click to select the image and make it bigger and in the center of the coverflow, and for the second click to follow the route.

Is it doable?

I use this coverflow: https://github.com/leon-good-life/coverflow-react

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the first click figure out to enlarge image ,You have to do a complete change in you css .*It is easier to add the enlargement when hovered, because that makes more sense* ,Anyway add counts to the `onClick` function you are using and then do the complete routing in that function when the `clickcCount` exedes you limit..